# Assign elements of 2d list before integer > 1 (python)

Tags: python

I want to make the preceding integers of a 2d list equal to a certain integer which is greater than 1. So for example if I have the input:

```
L = [[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The desired output would be:

```
[[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Here the two preceding integers of the `3` have to be set equal to this `3`, and the one preceding integer of the `2` have to be set equal to this `2`. Is there a systematical way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def maxafter(l):
    max = 1
    for elt in l:
        if elt > max: max = elt
        yield max
[[x for x in maxafter(l[::-1])][::-1] for l in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

start by reversing your lists, then browse them, and update them:

```
L = [[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
for index, item in enumerate(L):
   item.reverse()
   value = 1
   for list_index, element in enumerate(item):
       if element == 1:
           item[list_index] = value
       else:
           value = element
   item.reverse()
   L[index] = item
```